# Check if cell in column is duplicate and check if cell in another column is 0 vba

Tags: vba, excel

i need to check if a cell in a column (X:X) is a duplicate and if a cell in another column (AB:AB) is 0, and if the conditions match highlight the respective row in a color. This is what I have but it's not working..

```
Dim cell1 As Variant, myrngg1 As Range, clr1 As Long  
Set myrngg1 = Range("X1:X" & Cells(Rows.count, "X").End(xlUp).Row)
clr1 = 1
For Each cell1 In myrngg1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrngg1, cell1) > 1 And Range("AB" & clr1).Value = 0 Then
    cell1.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGrey
End If
clr1 = clr1 + 1
Next
```

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: @ScottCraner It's a part of a bigger macro that should automate a manual search operation

Comment: Turn on Option Explicit and you would see that you have a typo in your variable name `cell`.

Comment: @SJR yes, noticed it, corrected :D but still doesn't work..

Comment: please describe that it is doing or not doing.  ... `it's not working`  does not really do that

Comment: Instead of `Range("AB" & clr1).Value` use `Range("AB" & cell1.row).Value`  and get rid of the counter.

Comment: I can only assume one or both of the conditions are not met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one works for me. picks up both `0` and `"0"`

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cell1 As Variant, myrngg1 As Range
    Set myrngg1 = Range("X1:X" & Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell1 In myrngg1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrngg1, cell1) > 1 And cell1.EntireRow.Columns("AB").Value & "" = "0" Then
            cell1.EntireRow.Interior.Color = rgbGrey    ' vbGrey is undefined in my version of excel
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested yours:

```
Dim cell1 As Variant, myrngg1 As Range, clr1 As Long  
Set myrngg1 = Range("X1:X" & Cells(Rows.count, "X").End(xlUp).Row)
clr1 = 1
For Each cell1 In myrngg1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrngg1, cell1) > 1 And Range("AB" & clr1).Value = 0 Then
    cell1.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGrey
End If
clr1 = clr1 + 1
Next
```

Rebuilt using a for loop:

```
Dim i as Long, LR as Long
LR = Cells( Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR to 1 Step -1
    If Application.CountIf(Range(Cells(1,"X"),Cells(LR,"X")), Cells(i,"X").Value) > 1 AND CellS(i, "AB").Value = 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Colo = vbGrey
    End If
Next i
```

Both this and the one you've provided work for me; I have manually input values into col(X) and col(AB) to test... make sure you have formatted correctly the col(AB) so that it picks up zero and a number, not a string.

Comment: If you're having issues with format, use = "0" rather than = 0 to see if it fixes anything.